# ImageView with rotation in Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-imageview, animationdrawable

I need to make an imageview with rotation feature. So I looked at the android developers [site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). And used their codes. But somehow I get an error.

Error:`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable`

I have these codes:

```
ImageView refresh = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.refresh_devices_button);
refresh.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation); // The IDE says that it may produce null pointer exception
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) refresh.getBackground();
frameAnimation.start();
```

**In spin_animation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
</selector>
```

Please help me. From android's site I get the codes but their codes does not work. Maybe the problem is with my spin_animation.xml file.

`refresh.getBackground` returns `StateListDrawable`I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that android site is okay. The problem was with my xml file.
I had this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_1" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_2" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_3" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_4" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_5" android:duration="50" />
    </animation-list>
</selector>
```

Instead of the above code I used the following code. I had to remove the`<selector>` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
        ImageView splash = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(500);

        // Start animating the image

        splash.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rotation Animation to imageview**

```
 `RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
  anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
  anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
  anim.setDuration(700);

  // Start animating the image
  final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
  splash.startAnimation(anim);

  // Later.. stop the animation
 splash.setAnimation(null);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a rotation animation for my ImageView. You can try with this code: 
First create your xml for rotation animation in anim directory : 
rotation_animation.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

After that in your Java class (activity or fragment) add this :

```
Animation rotationAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation_animation);
yourImageView.startAnimation(rotationAnimation);
```

Now you are ready. Happy codding :)

Comment: I do not have anim directory. Should I add under res folder or under the app folder directly.

Comment: You need to create a new folder right click on res folder create new folder name it anim. And you can put your animation xmls in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and import below class as well.

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;



private AnimationDrawable mAnimation;
private ImageView mAnimLogo;

mAnimLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_image);
mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mAnimLogo.getDrawable();


 mAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line :

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) refresh.getBackground();
```

you are trying to cast a StateListDrawable to an AnimationDrawable which throws the exception.

Nice and simple :

```
refresh.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(...);
```

rotates your view to 360 Degrees clockwise in ... ms.

Or

```
 refresh.animate().rotationBy(360).setDuration(...);
```

rotates the view **BY** 360 degrees.

Check out [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) for different kinds of animations you can code in one line.

Comment: My duration is not known. I am scanning something so it must continue till it finishes the search.